# DC DC converter simulation time slow in lt spice

Tags: dc-dc-converter, simulation, ltspice, spice

Usually I can 'finagle' DC to DC converter simulations into working in a timely manner, this one has me stumped. I have done the standard gmin/abstol/reltol/cshunt combination, set initial conditions and I still can't get it to simulate more than 3ms before it bogs down and goes to fs/s on simulation time.

How can I get a DC to DC converter to simulate in a timely (us/s simulation time) manner?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried different MOS? A `.model`, rather than a `.subckt`. Or change with a VCSW for testing, maybe add some `Rpar` to the inductance, `Rser` and/or `Cpar` to simple voltage sources, combine C3/C4/R1, R12/C6, into a single cap, Vin/R2/Cin, same for output caps.  Also, it looks like you have an imposed timestep.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the circuit is quite obvious once you see it.
The values of C1, C2, C5, C8 and C9 are 0.1 which means 0.1 F.
A huge bootstrap cap (C2), a shorted sensing circuit (C5), a very slow soft-start (C1) .... numerous reasons why the simulation is slow and gives weird results.
The intended values probably are 0.1**u**F.